# How to run a subquery with alias in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following query which I am struggling to use in Laravel. `DB::raw()` is there but can't figure out how to set the subquery.

```
SELECT * from products
where status = 1
AND
id IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT `product_id` 
            FROM `order_product` 
        order by `id` desc limit 8
        ) as T
)
```

I am using Laravel 5.6

Comment: Are you asking how to write this with the query builder?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't test it yet but something like this should do the trick:

```
$products = Product
        ::where('status', 1)
        ->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
            $query
                ->select('product_id')
                ->from('order_product')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->take(8);
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' (SQL: select * from `products` where `status` = 1 and `id` in (select `product_id` from `order_product` order by `id` desc limit 8))`

Comment: this is what I was having the issue this is why I used sub-subquery.